# How to list the Ubuntu 20.04 processes that auto-start?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm aware how to configure services to auto-start from the command line, but I'm not sure how to see the ones already configured to auto-start.

I installed nginx earlier today from a custom repo and was surprised to see that it didn't auto-start when I rebooted.

I then went down the rabbit hole of trying to find the command to see only the services which auto-start.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `systemctl`. To list all services that are currently loaded and running on your system:

```
systemctl -t service --state=active
```

If you want to list services that start when your system boots then you can use:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
```